# How to approach for a list comprehension solution?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am practicing list comprehension but can't get the intuition properly.

For example, how can i should proceed step by step for this below code(It works perfectly, i have written it as a solution of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587585/how-to-map-words-from-two-differnt-text-files-in-python)) and transform this solution into list comprehension solution? An answer with a brief explanation will be great.

```
with open("example.txt","r") as first, open("output.txt","r") as second:

    for i,j in zip(first,second):
        first_list = i.split()
        second_list = j.split()
        for i,j in  zip(first_list, second_list):
            print i,j,
```

Comment: You are *printing* values. Did you want to produce a list with those values instead?

Comment: It won't matter, a list is ok. :)

Comment: It matters because it is *not clear* what your expected output is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would produce the innermost `i, j` values in a list of tuples:

```
with open("example.txt","r") as first, open("output.txt","r") as second:
    result = [(word1, word2) for line1, line2 in zip(first, second) for word1, word2 in zip(line1.split(), line2.split())]
```

I've replaced your variable names with ones that are less obtuse.

The above could be written out as nested loops with:

```
 for line1, line2 in zip(first, second):
     for word1, word2 in zip(line1.split(), line2.split():
         outputlist.append((word1, word2))
```

If you needed to have a *flat* list of the zipped words, then you need a 3rd loop:

```
with open("example.txt","r") as first, open("output.txt","r") as second:
    result = [word 
              for line1, line2 in zip(first, second)
              for combo in zip(line1.split(), line2.split())
              for word in combo]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i feel i am in a better state now :)

Answer (score 0):

With a list comprehension you can get a list of your expected values :

```
with open("example.txt","r") as first, open("output.txt","r") as second:
    my_list=[(t,k) for i,j in zip(first,second) for t,k in zip(i.split(),j.split())]
```

And then if you want to print the items you can loop over `my_list` and print them.

```
for i,j in my_list:
    print i,j
```